# Chrome display glitch when the GPU acceleration is on, AMD Catalyst driver

Tags: ati, google-chrome, radeon, catalyst, visual-artifacts

I have some graphics glitch when enable GPU acceleration in chrome. If I disable acceleration, it fix the glitch ; But in full HD most of flash videos frame rate drop, so very slow. :)

Any idea, what can i do?

I Upload 2 pics from glitch.

My hardware: `CM Hyper TX 3 on AMD A5300 with HD 7480D 6 GB RAM` . I use official AMD driver from amd.com, Ubuntu 14.04 (I upgraded from 12.04, in Ubuntu 12, same glitch with old drivers.)

I reinstalled x.org completely and purge all config files, but this didn't resolve the problem. If i use other drivers, I have some other problem ie.:nor automatic resolution change when connect new monitor, false refresh-rate for displays and etc.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PkrK.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMS22.jpg]

Comment: I've the exact same problem. I think it started with one of the last chrome updates. I also have the offical AMD driver installed.

Comment: This is either a bug in the AMD driver or Chrome - probably the AMD driver. Report it to AMD. Bug reports for the proprietary drivers go to http://ati.cchtml.com/

Comment: I found the dsolution, after all i replaced the 7480D with 5570 and the glitch is gone.

Comment: @Amoba when you say "replaced the 7480D with 5570" you mean you replaced the actual hardware, or just changed a setting in the config?

Comment: I actually change Videocard, disable the integrated and put on a discrette one.