# Chrome graphical glitches with AMD Catalyst proprietary driver

Tags: google-chrome, radeon, catalyst, amd-graphics

Same exact issue as [Chrome display glitch when the GPU acceleration is on, AMD Catalyst driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477854/chrome-display-glitch-when-the-gpu-acceleration-is-on-amd-catalyst-driver).

Graphical glitching happens periodically, maybe triggered by flash/javascript-heavy pages?

I'm pretty sure this started happening after Chrome switched from GTK+ to Aura.

on AMD Radeon HD 6670 w/ Catalyst 13.101-130523a-157671E-ATI, Ubuntu 12.04 w/ Cinnamon

Comment: I tested new Google Chrome too and I had similar issues I dislike this change but I guess this issue is rather be refered to Google Chrome support. They gonna fix it with time I guess.